# MoveClip.Visible and MouseEvent - ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Say I have the following;

```
public function onBellyPatch_Two(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            inBelly_Two.visible = true;
        }
```

> inBelly_Two is a MovieClip

I have two movieclips over top of each other, when you click one MovieClip another one shows up on top, and when you click that (second MovieClip)a textBox is updated.

I noticed that even if a movieclip object's visible property is false,  when you click in the area where the movie clip is the MouseEvent.CLICK event is called. Is there a way to get around this? I would like to stack movieClip.

I guess one way to get around this problem would be:
 removing the eventListener when movieClip is not visible and enabling the eventListener when moviclip is visible.

Is there some otherway?

Much Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:
inBelly_Two.buttonMode = false;

This will let onBellyPatch_Two be called no matter if inBelly_Two is visible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the listener, you can just say

```
mc.mouseEnabled = false;
```

[mouseEnabled docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled)